# What is the equivalent of 'pip download' in npm?

Tags: npm, pip

using `pip`, i can do pip download  and it will download the package and it's dependencies.

How do I do it in `npm`? I want to download all the the dependencies of my package.json file so I can install those locally on my workstation on-prem